# Static unordered_map pointer initialitation in C++

Tags: c++

I got this C++ code:

Client.h:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Client{
    static unordered_map<int, Client*>* clients;
public:
    static void initializeClients();
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

 void Client::initializeClients(){
     clients = new unordered_map<int, Client*>();
}
```

But the linker gives me a LNK2001 unresolved external symbol for the unordered_map. I have no idea of what I am doing wrong, but it seems that I am missing something. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Any idea? Thank you in advice!

Comment: There must be thousands of duplicates of this, but the short of it is that you're only *declaring* the static member variable, you're not defining it anywhere.

Comment: You are right. I missed it I don't know why (I even got it coded in another part of my code O o). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare clients in your cpp file :

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
unordered_map* Client::clients;

 void Client::initializeClients(){
     clients = new unordered_map<int, Client*>();
}
```

explenation:
header file only tells the linker what kinds of symbols some cpp file(s) has. declaring a variable in the header file does not makes this variable appear by it self. here you need to instantiate the static map pointer in the cpp file by declaring it , and make other files know about him by specifing it in the header file

summery :
static member variables and global variables need to be declared also in some cpp file in order to get instantiated